# php.ini updates not reflected in phpinfo() output

Tags: php, memory-limit, info

I am trying to update memory_limit in php.ini, but I don't see the value updated in phpinfo(). Here is the ini file path info from phpinfo():

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:  /etc
Loaded Configuration File:  /etc/php.ini
```

Updated /etc/php.ini and then ran:

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

I tried updating other values in ini file to see if anything gets updated, but nothing does.

I am on an AWS EC2 linux instance with wordpress.

Comment: Do you have a php-fpm service running? If so, you need to restart that. Restarting apache only helps if you are running the apache module mod_php (which is not the default these days)

Comment: That worked! If you want to add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many modern PHP installations run [PHP-FPM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php) by default, instead of as an Apache module mod_php. PHP-FPM is itself a separate service that needs to be restarted via your operating system's preferred method. e.g.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

You mentioned you already knew which php.ini to modify from the `phpinfo()` output. For future readers, the PHP-FPM service may use a different php.ini. Consult the output from `phpinfo()` when loaded via the web to find out which php.ini to modify.